# Make eclipse detect compilation errors in gwt client code

Tags: eclipse, gwt

Is it possible to configure Eclipse such that it will detect use of classes and methods not available to GWT and fail compilation early or maybe hide them from autocomplete ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO, there is no option in the google-eclipse-plugin yet.

In theory it could be feasible to call the gwt-compiler in draft mode after any single saving action, but this could be extremely slow.

With new features in last gwt version for super-devmode, this could be much faster because the compiler is able to perform incremental compilation. But I think it would not be faster enough.

Anyway you can try to add a task to compile your project any time you save a file:

Right click on the project -> Properties -> Builders -> New (call a script or an ant/maven task ...)

If you take a look to [CodeServer](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/release/2.6/dev/codeserver/java/com/google/gwt/dev/codeserver/CodeServer.java) and [Recompiler](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/release/2.6/dev/codeserver/java/com/google/gwt/dev/codeserver/Recompiler.java) classes you could figure out a way for coding a class with a very simple `main()` for recompiling your project from command line.

Comment: Thanks but that's way too slow. I can't stand anything longer than 1s. This shouldn't really need any form of compilation. AFAIK available classes can be cheaply calculated by analyzing .gwt.xml files.

Comment: That is not entirely true, apart from parsing gwt.xml, you must parse all java files in namespaces pointed by .gwt.xml in order to figure out all the imports and fully-qualified classes used in any portion of code, compile ui-binder files and run generators because generated classes could have references to external classes. I doubt this could be done in less than a second.

Comment: In order to build the full list of possible classes, an error checker would need to load your `.gwt.xml`, each `inherits` statement you have, each `inherits` *they* have and so on, and then look at all packages they reference with `source` or `super-source` tags - not just the packages themselves, but all possible types in those packages. IntelliJ does this efficiently - but it cheats, by having a preset list of things it thinks are valid, so if you add new emulation classes, it doesn't understand them, and *always* marks your code as broken, even when it isn't. Fast or correct, pick one!

Comment: You're tight Colin, the list of things to consider is getting bigger if you want to be sure all dependencies are satisfied. I dint know that feature in IntelliJ, it is nice anyway, there is nothing similar in eclipse though.

Comment: Why would I need to parse imports in java files ? Can imports and other references somehow influence which types are available to GWT code ?

Comment: If your code in class a.b.O uses the class in a.c.P, you have to be sure that a.c is defined in any of the gwt.xml you inherit. But when gwt compiles all the project it needs all the sources referenced in any single line of code. So, if there is a class a.d.Q used in a.c.P you have to check that class as well and so on. For instance, how would you deal with the compiler error when you try to use Calendar in a.c.P? the only option is to visit all the compiler class tree.